# PayPal transfering recived mony to many other users automaticly

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

i read that chained\parallel payments are restricted to 5\6 people.
what i want is when account recive money, to transfer x% to y other paypal accounts.
what do i need? and how can i do it?

Thank, Imbaro

Answer (score 0):

You could just let the money come to your own account and then automatically trigger payments to secondary users in real-time using the Pay API within an IPN solution.

Comment: Yep -- PayPal's split payments functionality can be useful for some use cases, but if your needs go beyond the limits then your alternative is to roll your own. This also would allow you to use other PayPal products besides Adaptive Payments, which may offer more overall functionality. This is dependent upon your business case accomodating the sender seeing your account as the recipient of the payment.